# Failed to load class error due to seemingly fine code

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, amazon-emr, spark-submit

I have been intermittently receiving the "Failed to load class [main class]" error due to seemingly working code and would like to understand why?

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx localtesting]$ spark-submit --master yarn --num-executors 1 --executor-cores 1 --class com.monster.SanitycheckForNewLine /home/ec2-user/localtesting/NextGenETL-testing.jar
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/spark/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/share/aws/redshift/jdbc/redshift-jdbc42-1.2.37.1061.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Error: Failed to load class com.monster.SanitycheckForNewLine.
22/06/07 20:32:14 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
22/06/07 20:32:14 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/tmp/spark-8150c3fa-715f-4475-ac15-b9881168c4ee
```

In this case, the specific line that is causing the error is in a property file named service_type.properties and the property itself is:

```
from=SCHEMA_NAME.SERVICE_TYPE ST
```

Now my code works when I set the property in question to be a random string (I used the character  as a test). Unfortunately, I have tried manually typing out the line of code, but the error persists (meaning that I am not looking at a special char lookalike issue) and I checked the newline character.

At this point, I am trying to understand both why this issue is occurring and how to more easily find the random lines of code that have seemingly no issues, but break in runtime **(I have seen this issue appear in the scala code itself too - I am just using the property file as an easy example)**.

Regarding my env, I am running maven with the following pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId><.../></groupId>
    <artifactId><.../></artifactId>
    <version><.../></version>

    <properties>
        <scala.version>2.12.2</scala.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.12</scala.binary.version>
        <scala.plugin.version>2.12.2</scala.plugin.version>
        <aws.sdk.bom.version>2.17.140</aws.sdk.bom.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-bom -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>${aws.sdk.bom.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazon.emr/emr-dynamodb-hadoop -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazon.emr</groupId>
            <artifactId>emr-dynamodb-hadoop</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.44</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ssm -->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ssm</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.44</version>
        </dependency>-->


       <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-sdk-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.15</version>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>dynamodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>ssm</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>secretsmanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-xml-protocol</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>sts</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
         
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.6.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <.../>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <scm>
        <.../>
  </scm>
</project>
```

SanitycheckForNewLine.scala:

```
import com.monster.utilities.constants.{info, log}

object SanitycheckForNewLine {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    log(info, "I'm sane!")
  }
}
```

Comment: "the specific line that is causing the error is in a property file named" –– How do you know? Why is it causing this error? "my code works when I set the property in question to be a random string"
 –– Why don't you do that? "Unfortunately, I have tried manually typing out the line of code, but the error persists " –– why "unfortunately", what line did you type, where did you type it, and what was the error, that "persists"? "meaning that I am not looking at a special char lookalike issue" –– what is that issue?

Comment: "I have seen this issue appear in the scala code itself too - I am just using the property file as an easy example" –– nothing easy about it. If you can come up with a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using pure scala, without any unnecessary external tools and libraries, you are much likely to get good answers.

Comment: "Error: Failed to load class com.monster.SanitycheckForNewLine." –– What is that class? What does it do? The error looks like it is throwing some kind of exception during initializaton. Adding/increasing logging level might help troubleshoot

Comment: How do you know? Why is it causing this error? - I know that line is causing the problem because the code runs correctly when I change the variable the the letter a. It is worth noting, that I am not actually using this property my code yet and want to understand the issue. If I knew why it is causing the error, I would not have posted.

Comment: I decided to use the property example because the scala error was less easily communicated - identical code threw the error depending on if it was copy/pasted vs hand typed, but when I check for any special hidden chars, nothing appeared. Hence, I did not consider that reproducible enough to post about.

Comment: I'll see what I can do about getting better logging, but that will not be a quick process. I'll also add the class, but it is a simple testing class that prints a single line.

Comment: > the code runs correctly when I change the variable the the letter a --- What variable? What "letter a"? " decided to use the property example because the scala error was less easily communicated " –– Well, what you communicated so far hasn't been "easy" by any measure. I for one still have _absolutely no idea_ what you are talking about (and neither do anyone else if lack of answers is any indication). > identical code threw the error depending on if it was copy/pasted vs hand typed, -- What code? What error? Copy-pasted where? From where? Hand-typed where?